# How to stop a Website, NOT a Website Application Project from reloading when getting latest from TFS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution bound to TFS source control. Every time I publish, check in or get latest I prompted to reload a Website in the solution, note this is a Website, not a Web Application Project:

[image]

I do not want to do below in italics, although it is a solution but ONLY for getting latest, when publishing, I am still prompted to reload on Publish even though "Detect when a file is changed outside environment" is unchecked:

*Go to Options menu. Tools > Options > Environment > Documents and unchecking checkbox called "Detect when a file is changed outside environment"*

**Is there anyway to stop this from happening?**

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting from Options menu.
Tools > Options > Environment > Documents and uncheck checkbox called "Detect when a file is changed outside environment"

Comment: I thought you might say that, I like having that feature on though but perhaps it is the only way